# Regexp, that ignores only first capture group

Tags: regex

We have tab spaced list of "key=value" pairs.

How we can split it, using regexp?

Case `key=value` must be transformed into `value`. Case `key=value=value2` must be transformed into `value=value2`.

https://regex101.com/r/dR5dT0/1 - I've started solution like this, but can't find beautiful way to remove only "key=" part from text.

**UPD** BTW, do you know cool crash courses on regular expressions?

Comment: BTW, if you need a great regex testing site - [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) (for PHP, JS, Python) and [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) and [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) for .NET are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
=(\S*)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU9qU4/1)

Since the list is already formatted, the `=` in the pattern will always be the name/value delimiter.

The `\S` matches any non-whitespace character.

The `*` is a quantifier meaning that the `\S` should occur zero or more times (`\S*` matches zero or more non-whitespace characters).

Comment: Николай, I can recommend [regexone.com](http://regexone.com) to start learning regex. Besides, there are two very nice resources: [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) and [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) - you can learn very cool and advanced tricks there.

Comment: Wiktor, much simpler than I thought. Thanks! Both answers are nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
/\w+=(\S+)/
```

and grab captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dR5dT0/2)